# An incomplete crossword

Tags: word, wordplay, word-property, crosswords

[image: Crossword]

**Across:**

```
0. One letter replaced, I am your relative. (4 letters)

1. One letter replaced, I am a country. (3 letters)

4. One letter replaced, I am vehicles. (5 letters)

6. Two letters replaced, you call me. (4 letters)

7. One letter replaced, I start. (5 letters)
```

**Down:**

```
2. One letter replaced, I am a singer. (5 letters)

3. A Korean beer. (5 letters)

5. One letter replaced, I am a mammal. (5 letters)

8. One letter replaced, I am surjective. (4 letters)

9. One letter replaced, I am a bird. (4 letters)
```

**IMPORTANT!:**

The "words" are incomplete. Consider the oddity, and you'll see their complete version.

**Subtle Hint:**

> The "words" are incomplete, as they are just prefixes of the complete versions.

**Moderate Hint:**

> To be complete, they require suffixes, which are complete words themselves.

**Decisive Hint:**

> The suffixes are already shown.

**Very Decisive Hint:**

> Revelation 1:8, Revelation 21:6, Revelation 22:13.

**Very² Decisive Hint:**

> Bravo!

**Very³ Decisive Hint:**

> https://www.hitejinro.com/ (Not an advertisement, but one of the words is shown here.)

Comment: Would suggest putting the number of letters beside each clue

Comment: An observation. Your hints appear to point towards rot13(gur ANGB cubargvp nycunorg. Nf fhpu, gurer ner frireny pbqrjbeqf juvpu ner nantenzf bs gur pyhrf bapr n yrggre unf orra gnxra njnl, r.t. 4. BFPNE = PNEF + B, 5. GNATB = TBNG + A, 7. QRYGN = YRNQ + G.) Is there any mileage in this or am I barking up the wrong tree altogether?

Comment: @Stiv rot13(Vg unf fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu ANGB cubargvp pbqrf, ohg ol "njnl" V zrna punenpgre(f) zhfg or ercynprq, abg gnxra njnl.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the completed crossword

> [image]

Clue Explanations

> 0. **NADA**, with one letter replaced, becomes **NANA** (or **DADA**), a relative.
>  1. **UNA**, with one letter replaced, becomes **USA**.
>  2. **BISSO**, with one letter replaced, becomes **BASSO**
>  3. **TERRA** is a Korean beer (see last very decisive hint)
>  4. **KARTE**, with one letter replaced, becomes **KARTS**
>  5. **PANTA**, with one letter replaced, becomes **PANDA**
>  6. **SOXI**, with two letters replaced, becomes **TAXI** (this one's a bit ambiguous but I think it's right).
>  7. **SETTE**, with one letter replaced, becomes **SET TO** (which requires breaking up the word, but was the closest thing I could find).
>  8. **OKTO**, with one letter replaced, becomes **ONTO**
>  9. **NOVE**, with one letter replaced, becomes **DOVE**

Why are these the answers

> Each answer corresponds to the prefix of the [NATO phonetic codename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) for the corresponding clue number where the number is the suffix of the codename. For example, the NATO phonetic codename for **three** is **terrathree** which is why answer **3** is **TERRA**.